# Why can't I run a .py file that only has a print function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alright just for context I'm an extreme newbie to python (around 15 minutes of experience).

My question is most likely a dumb one, but I'm gonna ask it anyways as I can't find anything about it elsewhere; Why can't I run the (very advanced) code below as a .py file? Using version 3.6 if it matters.

```
print("hello")
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to run your file?

Comment: run it online: www.pyfiddle.io ... looks fine

Comment: How are you running it? From a command line, etc. ?

Comment: I'm running it by opening the .py file directly

Comment: [How to Run Your Python Scripts](https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/)

Comment: @YungBruh, ..."opening the .py file directly" *how*, exactly? If through an operation like a double-click in your operating system's file manager, which operating system is that, and which specific operation? (If it's Windows, and you right-click, the default operation for a double click will be bolded; which menu item, if any, is shown in bold in that case?)

Answer (score 2):

Opening the python file will not cause it to execute.
Depending on your operating system (Windows, Mac, Linux) try opening a
command window and navigating to the file location of you python file.
Once you are in the directory (folder) of the python file that contains 
the print statement run the following:
python myfile.py

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=mac[Pycharm][1]

It is an IDE (Integrated Developer Environment). Pycharm will have what you need to write, save and execute python code all in the same application. There are others of course but Pycharm is as good as any to start with.

Good luck!

Comment: give some information like what's your operating system? how are you try to run it?